# Matlab plot removing space around graph

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

Some of my codes are as follows :

```
date = datenum(num2str(f_0), 'yyyymmdd'); % f_0 is like 20120102 20120102...20120310.
y_1 = plot(handles.axes2, date, f_1)
hold on
grid on
ax = gca;
ax.YAxis.Exponent = 0;
xlabel('Date[year - month - day]')
ylabel('Price')
datetick('x','yy-mm-dd')
```

I've got the desired result, but there were some spaces in both sides of the plot. To remove them, I've tried 'axis tight'. It pretty worked, but a problem is that it is applied to both the x-axis and the y-axis. I want only x-axis to be applied. One more important thing is that both start date and last date of the plot have been disappeared! My goal is to maintain a state('only x-aixs tight')and I want to show all the existing x-axis values including the start date(the point that graph starts) and the last date(the point that graph ends).
I've already tried 'xlim', but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After plot, you can use:

```
axis([a b c d])
```

where:

- a => initial value of x axis
- b => final value of x axis
- c => minimum value of y axis
- d => maximum value of y axis